# Layout: TextView at the top and ListView at the center

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently my ListView is exactly below my TextView. How can I make the ListView at the center of the screen while my TextView maintain its position on top?

Below is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/hp_color"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityText"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/condDescr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cityText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/condDescr"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can show with picture how you want design layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

And although I'm no expert here, it's my impression that there's little point to having a ListView in a LinearLayout. Both are scrollable (which isn't advised) and there's not much point if LinearLayout only has one child.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I removed the _LinearLayout_ and added `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the _ListView_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gravity to place the listview in center of the screen.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/hp_color"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityText"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/condDescr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cityText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/condDescr"
            **android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"**
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mainListView"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```